# D3 - Can't get popover to appear at cursor xy coordinate

Tags: javascript, d3.js, cursor-position

I'm trying to get nodes to show an adjacent popover when clicked. Here's a codepen on where I'm at:
https://codepen.io/SavanaPope/pen/abLdmbz?editors=1000

I've gotten very close, the popover currently shows in the upper-left corner, and is taking in on-click x/y data. It's just not getting the correct cursor location - I'm not sure how it's getting the pixel data currently.

I assume the issue has something to do with the clicknode function:

```
function clicknode(nodes) {
  const[x, y] = d3.pointer(event);
  tooltip.style("left", (x)+"px")
         .style("top", (y)+"px")
         .transition().duration(200).style("opacity", 0.9)

  loadTooltipContent(nodes);
}
```

But I just can't figure out where my (likely) formatting is wrong.

If you have any ideas on how to solve this, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **D3 V7**, rewrite `clicknode` as follows:

```
function clicknode(event, nodes) {
  tooltip
    .style("left", `${event.layerX}px`)
    .style("top", `${event.layerY}px`);
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you!! You solved both of my issues (popover position AND getting the csv data to load into a popover).